# Ajax GET request: x-access-token header not recieved in backend

Tags: node.js, ajax, get

I'm trying to send an AJAX GET request to a Node.js microservice. The request should have in the header `{'x-access-token': somtoken}` and my request is as follows:

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/api/books",
   headers: {'x-access-token' : sometoken},
   success: function(dataString) { 
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataString));
   }, error: function(error) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
});
```

However, the header recieved in the microservice is the following:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
origin: 'null',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36',
'access-control-request-headers': 'x-access-token',
accept: '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }
```

and so, it sends a response with error 403

The service is working correctly when sending the request from Postman.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The request headers you are looking at are only those for the pre-flight request ... you first of all need to get your service to answer that one correctly, before the actual request can happen.

Comment: Sounds like it's most likely an issue with the formatting of your token, what does a "token" look like?

Comment: @CBroe , can you please elaborate? And why is this not happening when I send the request from Postman?

Comment: @James , the token is hashed (which is too long for this comment to accept).
Again, It is working fine when sent from Postman

Comment: This is not happening when you use postman, because in that case it is not a client-side cross-domain request ... Go read up on CORS, if keywords like preflight request don’t mean anything to you yet.

Comment: @CBroe , I already added the following in my microservice to evaluate requests:

`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Access-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`

And it worked fine for POST requests (from browser but don't need a token). What else should I do?

Comment: You need to handle two requests in your server-side component, the initial OPTIONS request, and then the POST request afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code manually did the job for POST reauests but not for GET with x-access-token

However, I fixed it by using [cores npm package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) hook from jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/api/books",
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', token);
  },
  success: function (dataString) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataString));
  }, error: function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});
```

Comment: Still the same behavior.
However, shouldn't it be `xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', token);` instead of `xhr.setRequestHeader('x- access - token', token);`